# Supporting multiple screen sizes and rotations in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Firstly I wanna say that I red probably all there is on internet on this topic.
I kinda get the picture about it but still I am not sure, and my brain is boiling trying to think about how it should go properly so I need somebody to clarify me these things maybe better than I found at other tutorials and topics.
Also a lot of questions and answers are kinda old and I know that these qualifiers for layouts like small, large and xlarge are kinda deprecated so refreshing would be nice.
So the thing that bothers me is how to support multiple screen sizes and orientations in android?
I understand that I need to support different drawable resources for different screen density's and that I need to use smallest width available qualifier for different screen sizes.
The thing that is the problem and I don't understand is how to accompany both of that together.
For instance for first example I have like logo sign which should draw over the whole screen of the mobile.
Can I actually provide all possible solutions and all possible sizes of that logo in all orientations or the android will size them as needed from the closest ones I give him?
How does the smallest width qualifier go in hand with different density drawable resources?
They just change the size of the picture depending on the screen dpi but they don't change the layout appearance.
Should I change layouts depending on screen sizes, and the pictures will change according to the density by itself what is actually a second example, because like buttons are different story, if they are 50 x 50 px in mdpi they will be 100 x 100 px in xhdpi.
And that's what I kinda get.
The bigger problem is how to put in the picture all alone that is filling the screen by itself and also to take screen rotations and changing of width and height with it in account.
So it was a long question, hope I told you what you need to know, the similar questions have already been asked but they are kinda old and outdated in some parts, and even there I still didn't find all the answers I was looking for so I hope I will find them here.
Looking forward for your help and thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you're over complicating the topic, to support all sizes/layouts, you just have to keep them in mind while designing your layout. A vast majority of your layouts should only need to be built once and if they're built in a way that scales well it'll work out.

For example, if you're trying to draw a splash screen with a logo in the center, you can do something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/my_logo" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This would work on all devices/sizes/orientations as it is just putting the logo in the center.

When building a layout, just focus on an average size of a current modern phone but keep in mind people have smaller devices. Use that as your base for assets, and try to include smaller ones, or use vector images.

And if you're building a View that is long, wrap it in a `ScrollView` so it can scroll on smaller devices.

I would only ever use the other layout directories ( for sizing or orientation ) for very specific cases, like when you want to completely change how your layout looks.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir! The problem is that every person gives other solution to this problem, somebody saying you should use multiple directories, others you shouldn't, then you don't know where to go. I will try to do it the way you said, for like cellphones of similar size i won't change any layouts, only provide different bitmaps for different densities and build it with constraint layout and then maybe change layouts for like tablets or something similar.